# Импорт собственной системы модулей EcmaScript в NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, модули, экран

> app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const add = require('../index.js');

fs.readdir("../" ,(err ,data) => {
console.log(data);
data.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file + "\t\t" + path.extname(file) + "\t\t" + 
    fs.statSync("../" + file).size + "B");});
fs.writeFile('./../Projects/new.txt','red' ,(err)=>{
    if(err)console.log(err);});});
```

> index.js

```
import JSONgenerator from "./modules/generators/JSONgenerator.js";
import SVGgenerator from "./modules/generators/SVGgenerator.js";
import TXTgenerator from "./modules/generators/TXTgenerator.js";

import View from "./modules/view.js";
import Interface from "./modules/interface.js"; 
import Mouse from "./modules/mouse.js";

const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;
const size = width / height;

const body = document.body;


const view = new View(body ,width ,height ,size);


const face = new Interface(body ,size);
const mouse = new Mouse(view.canvas ,body);


const JSONG = new JSONgenerator(view.color);
const SVGG = new SVGgenerator(body ,width ,height);
const TXTG = new TXTgenerator();


window.view = view;
window.mouse = mouse;
window.face = face;
window.JSONG = JSONG;
window.SVGG = SVGG;
window.TXTG = TXTG;
```

> Консоль

> $ node app
> C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTMLNote\public_html\index.js:1
> import JSONgenerator from "./modules/generators/JSONgenerator.js";
> ^^^^^^
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTMLNote\public_html\node\app.js:6:1
> 3)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

Версия NodeJS : 14.17.0

> Update 0

> index.js

```
const JSONgenerator = require("./modules/generators/JSONgenerator.js");
const SVGgenerator = require("./modules/generators/SVGgenerator.js");
const TXTgenerator = require("./modules/generators/TXTgenerator.js");

const View = require("./modules/view.js");
const Interface = require("./modules/interface.js"); 
const Mouse = require("./modules/mouse.js");
```

> Консоль

> export default class JSONgenerator {
> ^^^^^^

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTMLNote\public_html\index.js:1:23)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

P.S
Package.json без изменений .

> Update 1

```
module.exports = class JSONgenerator {};
```

> Консоль

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

npm install window

> Консоль

> document is not defined

```
const body = window.document.body;
```

Comment: node не поддерживает js-модули за умолчанием. Нужно заменить import'ы на require, настроить транспилятор вроде babel, или думаю предпочтительный вариант в вашем заменить расширения всех файлов js-модулей с .js на .mjs, что говорит node, что вы используете es6 import'ы

Comment: В файле `package.json` проекта добавляете `"type": "module"`. Меняете все устаревшие `require` на `import`. Если это не конечное приложение и/или может использоваться как зависимость, читаем как реализуется экспорт [здесь](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points).

Comment: первый листинг кода похож на nodejs, второй на client-side, вы не запутались?

Comment: index.js - основной файл для модуля ,input ,интерфейс и т.д и т.п ,app.js - диспетчер файлов и создаёт файлы(он не готов ,вот ищу ,как подключить в единую систему) .Можно и как-то иначе ,через вызов html ,но ещё не знаю ,как подтягивать остальные файлы "сайта" .

Comment: nodejs понимает import/export из файлов `mjs`: [Modules: ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules)

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, `Nodejs` использует `CommonJS` модули.

[`ECMAScript` модули](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) можно использовать

- в файлах с раcширением `.mjs`
- указав [свойство `type`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type) в package.json: `"type": "module"`
- указав флаг `--input-type=module`